# Inconsistent column width when printing emojis with Tabulate

Tags: python, terminal, emoji, column-width, tabulate

I am trying to print out emojis as a table using `tabulate`, but not getting the right alignment. How can I fix that?

```py
emojis = [['', '', '', '', '', '', ''], 
          ['', '', '', '', '', '', ''], 
          ['', '', '', '', '', '', ''], 
          ['', '', '', '', '', '', ''], 
          ['', '', '', '', '', '', ''], 
          ['', '', '', '', '', '', ''], 
          ['', '', '', '', '', '', '']]
print(tabulate(emojis, tablefmt="fancy_grid"))
```

This is the output:

```
╒═══╤═══╤═══╤═══╤═══╤═══╤═══╕
│  │  │  │  │  │  │  │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│  │  │  │  │  │  │  │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│  │  │  │  │  │  │  │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│  │  │  │  │  │  │  │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│  │  │  │  │  │  │  │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│  │  │  │  │  │  │  │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│  │  │  │  │  │  │  │
╘═══╧═══╧═══╧═══╧═══╧═══╧═══╛
```

Comment: What terminal are you using, on what OS? I tried your exact example on ubuntu 20.04 and default terminal `xterm-265color` and works fine. Interestingly enough, in [the documentation](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/), the part about *tablefmt="fancy_grid"* is shown correct on Chrome on ubuntu, but shows the same error as your when opened on Chrome on Windows. So the operating system is something to think about.

Comment: Working on `Windows` `Bash` terminal.

Comment: Ubuntu has environmental variable `LANG` set to `"en_GB.UTF-8"`, while Windows has it set to `C` or unset. Try [setting this variable](https://support.shotgunsoftware.com/hc/en-us/articles/114094235653-Setting-global-environment-variables-on-Windows) `LANG` to value `en_GB.UTF-8` and then run your program. If it didn't work, consider reinstalling `tabulate` package after setting the `LANG` var and running program again.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's no solution for this at present, since, as hinted in the comments, each OS/Terminal/font renders emojis differently (see examples below). If your application permits it, my suggestion would be to export it as SVG/HTML/Markdown/etc., which force rigid column boundaries when rendered, e.g.

```py
print(tabulate(emojis, tablefmt="html"))
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

- Android, Slack code block:
  [image]
- Windows, Slack code block:

[image]

- Windows, Pycharm:

[image]

- Linux, terminal

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Terminal/console support will vary between operating systems, and specific terminal emulators.

In general Emoji and CJK characters are treated as a width of two terminal cells, rather than one terminal cell. So printing or displaying in console/terminal tends to get thrown out of line when CJK or emoji characters are involved.

`tabulate` uses the `wcwidth` module to handle "wide" characters. There are two approaches:

1. Install `wcwidth`, then install `tabulate`
2. Install `tabulate` with wide character support, which will install `wcwidth` as well as tabulate.

Refer to tabulate [readme](https://github.com/astanin/python-tabulate#wide-fullwidth-cjk-symbols).

Answer (score 0):

Emojis are usually two characters and not one, so `tabulate` with its default config will treat it as one character and your columns will look incorrectly padded.

You need to install `tabulate` along with its optional `widechars` dependency for [wide character support](https://github.com/astanin/python-tabulate?tab=readme-ov-file#wide-fullwidth-cjk-symbols) (which you need for emojis).

This will work:

```bash
pip3 install 'tabulate[widechars]'
```

No extra config is needed; your code will then 'just work'.